# how can I define variable in .htaccess file and use it?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have defined an htaccess file for my website having this code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^bit_auth\/?(.*)$ /cig/base3/auth/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|assets|themes|includes)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /cig/base3/index.php/$1 [L]
```

I want to **keep my site root path in a variable** like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
SetEnv BASE_PATH "/cig/base3"

RewriteRule ^bit_auth\/?(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE_PATH}/auth/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|assets|themes|includes)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE_PATH}/index.php/$1 [L]
```

because I may need to use `BASE_PATH` value in more codes later and also it may be changed and I don't want to search and replace every time in my htaccess file.
But when I use code above, **in htaccess file `%{ENV:BASE_PATH}` is returning an empty value rather than expected `/cig/base3`** but **in php when I call it using:**

```
<?php $specialPath = getenv('BASE_PATH'); var_dump($specialPath)?>
```

**it is showing the correct value of `/cig/base3`.**

Whats the problem in my codes and how can I solve this?

Comment: There's a quirk in the order in which Apache loads/runs modules - mod_rewrite always runs before SetEnv so you can't use SetEnv to set an environment variable you want to use in a RewriteRiule; however you **can** set the variable with a RewriteRule; e.g. `RewriteRule .* - [E=BASE_PATH:/cig/base3]`

Comment: @CD001 I did not exactly understand why should I use it this way but when I inserted your code in my htaccess file it is working as expected. do you have any references for more description/details and also examples for non-experienced users? or please describe it more.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can't use `SetEnv` that way because it's not processed yet.

> The internal environment variables set by this directive are set after
>   most early request processing directives are run, such as access
>   control and URI-to-filename mapping. If the environment variable
>   you're setting is meant as input into this early phase of processing
>   such as the RewriteRule directive, you should instead set the
>   environment variable with SetEnvIf.

What you are looking for is `setenvif` instead of `SetEnv`

So you should be able do something like

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^.*" base_path=/cig/base3
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_setenvif.html#setenvif

Comment: ^ @mrez.ir This is what I was getting at with my comment... I'm at work so I've not really got time to write a fully formatted coherent answer ;) SetEnvIf (unlike SetEnv) will run before mod_rewrite - but you can also set the environment variable with mod_rewrite itself - either works.

Comment: but both answers are correct I can not understand why should I do that in these ways? and wich one is more correct?

Comment: @mrez.ir - both doing the same thing, just in different ways - either way, you end up with an environment variable set. I prefer doing it through a RewriteRule if I'm using the variable with RewriteRules... but it really doesn't matter.

Comment: Does it slows original htaccess behavior? I mean loading somethings twice?

Comment: @mrez.ir .htaccess is only read once when the directory is scanned but .htaccess is read on every request and everything is processed accordingly. So it won't really introduce anymore slowness than it's default behavior.