# Can I pick of environment variables inside .htaccess somehow?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a set of apache (2.4.25) sites that use mod_vhost_alias so the one vhost services multiple subdomains.

I want to be able to set a environment variable, say

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>`
ServerNameAlias *.whatever-it-is.com
SetEnv HOME_URL https://www.whatever-it-is.com/
# etc
```

then in my various sites .htaccess files pick up that variable. So a site might allow access to a subfolder or a specific file and redirect everything back to the home site.

```
php_flag engine off
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/myapp[/]?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^favicon.ico
RewriteRule (.*)  %{HOME_URL}  [R=301,L]
#                   ^--- not working, how would you do it?
```

then in the case where I need to change the home_url across all sites, I can just apply it in the vhost and each of the dozens of subdomain sites will pick it up.

* also tried

```
RewriteRule (.*)  %{ENV:HOME_URL}  [R=301,L]
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/env.html
The %{ENV:variable} form of TestString in the RewriteCond allows mod_rewrite's rewrite engine to make decisions conditional on environment variables...

Comment: `RewriteRule (.*)  %{ENV:HOME_URL}  [R=301,L]`?

Comment: Also tried `RewriteRule (.*) %{ENV:HOME_URL} [R,L]`, as per http://stackoverflow.com/a/7749784/1238884 - still not working. Ends up in a redirect loop, as if the environment variable isn't being set (which it is, as I can see it from php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SetEnvIf` to set your environment variable so that it is available for `mod_rewrite` later in .htaccess.

Inside `VirtualHost` config have it like this:

```
SetEnvIf Host ^ HOME_URL=https://www.whatever-it-is.com/
```

Then inside .htaccess have a simple rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule .* %{ENV:HOME_URL} [R=301,L]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this change.

Comment: Well, it doesn't look too different to what I had already tried but this is now working for my subdomains

Comment: @frumbert There is more descriptive answer to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30399556/2721611)