# How to get visible query string and not parsed query string by rules or htaccess in PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess, get, query-string

I have a url that parts of it are converted into variables through htaccess and other parts are variables sent in GET.

```
mydomain.com/page/5/string?v2=foo&v3=bar
```

.httaccess sends 5 as a variable, let's call it v1

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ page.php?v1=$2 [L,QSA]
```

And the rest of the query string are received as GET.

```
?v2=foo&v3=bar
```

In this example, it is very straight forward, but in the actual system the variables parsed by .htaccess are more than one and are dynamic,

I need to find a way to only get the variables sent in GET ignoring the ones from .htaccess.

I tried `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` but that one returns also the variables parsed by .htaccess:

```
echo $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] //returns v1=5&v2=foo&v3=bar
```

I only want to get `v2=foo&v3=bar`

Comment: You could probably start with [strlok](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtok.php) or [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) on `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` using `?` as the character to search for...

Comment: Thanks, your link to strlok doesn't work.

Comment: I got my `()` and `[]` mixed up in the comment and garbaged it while editing it - fixed now ;)

Comment: ... forgot `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` doesn't contain the querystring - so exploding on `?` won't work anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can read `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and use proper regex to take the GET variables from URL. And then (if you need) you could write function to split them to array of variables:

```
$get = array(); //array for GET values
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

$uri_parts = explode('?', $uri, 2);
$get_string = $uri_parts[1]; //[0] is address

$get_pairs = explode('&', $get_string); //split to key=value pairs
foreach($get_pairs as $get_pair){
  list($key, $value) = explode('=', $get_pair, 2); //split key and value
  $get[$key] = $value;
}
```

`$get_string` contains string like `a=bc&d=ef`

`$get` contains key-value pairs (like `$_GET`)

Comment: Example for this?

Comment: This should really be a comment - if you're going to answer a question, answer it properly rather than playing the *fastest draw in the West* game

Comment: Okay, I added an example

Comment: This works!!! amazing, what about just '$get_string = substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], strrpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '?') +1);' I think is more elegant, but it works

Comment: I used explode because i think it's less complex but your way is also good

Answer (score 1):

> I need to find a way to only get the variables sent in GET ignoring the ones from .htaccess.

You can use an environment variable to pass original query string to your `php` file:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ page.php?v1=$2 [E=qs:%{QUERY_STRING},L,QSA]
```

Now access original query string using this variable in php code:

```
$_SERVER["REDIRECT_qs"]
```

This should print:

```
v2=foo&v3=bar
```

Whereas `$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]` will give you full query string i.e. `v1=5&v2=foo&v3=bar`

Comment: Thanks! This is very good, but I am looking for a PHP solution. I am not sure if I will be allowed to touch the htaccess.

Comment: Well ti doesn't change the rule behavior at all. It just passes an additional env variable to php code and bonus is that no additional coding needed in php.

Answer (score 0):

[how can I define variable in .htaccess file and use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30399109/how-can-i-define-variable-in-htaccess-file-and-use-it)

Example

```
SetEnv SPECIAL_PATH /foo/bin
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_env.html#setenv

Comment: Didn't think you could set dynamic environment variables in htaccess? If you try to set it to ${QUERY_STRING}, it'll set it to be the literal string rather than the value